# Low sound output with Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, audio

I just bought a new Gateway tower with Windows 8 and the sound output is extremely low, despite all volume settings being at max. I've done a system update but nothing changed. When I put headphones into the jack, however, the sound is normal. I've looked around for answers but none of them seemed to work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check the speakers that they actually work; jack may be bad, look at the outputs, maybe a line out could be used for speakers

Answer (score 1):

I very much doubt that this is happening to you, but it happened to me one time.
The "phase" of 1 speaker was incorrect, and when the stereo speakers combined sound was heard, they literally canceled eachother out.

It was one of the odder troubleshooting things for me. any audio person would know how important "phase" is,  for me it was just strange.
When I hooked up the headphones the sound was much louder, because the other speaker could not cancel the sound from the other speaker.

In my situation I had wired up a connector wrongly. Anywhere along the way if the polarity of the signal be it at the line level or the amped output is reversed to one speaker, the phase would be wrong, and that could happen.

What was occuring is while one speaker was going back and forth, the other speaker was going forth and back, the sound pressures being opposite somewhat canceled eachother out , the end result was just very low sound, it was not really bad sound.

Other than cute stories, you have not provided enough information to know your whole setup, what the speaker setup is your using?  Some more information, or pictures of your set-up and connections would be useful.  How is it connected?  What is the method of connection?  what are the speakers? Etc.